# How do I turn off the external microphone?

Tags: sound

I am running ubuntu 11.10 with ardour doing track audio. I am having an issue in being unable to turn off the mic on the laptop. The system setting for ubuntu audio seemidly does not have option to change the mic input

Answer (score 1):

If you click the sound indicator icon on the top right of the screen you'll find the `Sound Settings`. Once that is open, go to the `Input` tab. There should be a pull down menu to the right of `Connector` which should allow you to select your microphone input. Once that is done, click the mute check box found to the right of the `Input volume` slider (not the Output volume one above it).

Comment: doesnt work for me.